# Alias not working with for loop

Tags: bash, shell, ssh, alias

I tried to copy the zip file from localhost to two remote machines, I aliased my remote hostnames.

Hence I use the `for` loop like this

```
 for g in hy1 hy2;do scp kube.tar.gz $g:~;done
```

**hy1,hy2**- alias for remote hostnames

when I ran this command, It returns the following error

> ssh: Could not resolve hostname hy1: Name or service not known
>
> lost connection
>
> ssh: Could not resolve hostname hy2: Name or service not known
>
> lost connection

Is there any problem with using alias for file sharing, with loop ?

Comment: For most shells (I believe zsh is an exception), a shell alias is only used for the command/utility _name_ i.e. the _first token_ of a command. You can set a shell _variable_ and use that with `$` anywhere (except singlequotes). For hostnames in `scp` and `ssh` you can configure nicknames or other synonyms in `ssh_config` q.v.

Comment: What command did you use to create these aliases and what shell are you using?

Comment: @jlliagre Iam using bash shell, I add alias in **.bashrc** file  `alias hy1='ssh vahaidom@h1'
alias hyp='ssh vahai@master'`

Answer (score 2):

Aliases are for commands, you want variables here:

```
hy1=vahaidom@h1
hy2=vahai@master
for g in $hy1 $hy2; do scp kube.tar.gz ${g}: ; done
```